python3 osmWebWizard.py is not working in Ubuntu 22.04
The command
python3 osmWebWizard.py

is generating a pop-up

Problem loading page

I am using Firefox Web browser in Ubuntu 22.04
I am referring this for running sumo simulator.
I searched in the sumo documentation but didn't found any solution


Found the solution! The problem is the default snap version on firefox installed in Ubuntu 22.04. I just installed .deb version of firefox and everything is working fine.

It is actually already a FAQ to use a deb package instead of snap:
https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/FAQ.html#osmwebwizardpy_fails_to_load_the_browser_page_on_linux
